# How do I populate text fields made by QT Designer?

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt4

I'm trying to create a function similar to this:

1. Select User from drop down menu
2. Selection fills in text fields in the UI with preset information based on the user.
3. Information is written to an excel spreadsheet.

I covered step 1 already and step 3 but I can't figure out how to go about getting step 1 to post information into the fields of a QT Designer UI.

```
class Ui_CheckIn(QtGui.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)

def setupUi(self, CheckIn):
    self.chkin_reg_descr = QtGui.QLabel(self.CheckIn)
    self.chkin_reg_descr.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 340, 111, 21))
    self.chkin_reg_descr.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("chkin_reg_descr"))
    self.chkin_reg_descr_in = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.CheckIn)
    self.chkin_reg_descr_in.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 340, 501, 21))
    self.chkin_reg_descr_in.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("chkin_reg_descr_in"))
    self.chkin_reg_asset_in = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.CheckIn)
    self.chkin_reg_asset_in.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 310, 221, 20))
    self.chkin_reg_asset_in.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("chkin_reg_asset_in"))
    self.chkin_reg_asset = QtGui.QLabel(self.CheckIn)
    self.chkin_reg_asset.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 310, 111, 21))
    self.chkin_reg_asset.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("chkin_reg_asset"))
    self.chkin_reg_serial = QtGui.QLabel(self.CheckIn)
    self.chkin_reg_serial.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 310, 71, 21))
    self.chkin_reg_serial.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("chkin_reg_serial"))
    self.chkin_reg_serial_in = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.CheckIn)
    self.chkin_reg_serial_in.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 310, 191, 20))
    self.chkin_reg_serial_in.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("chkin_reg_serial_in"))
    self.chkin_reg_submit = QtGui.QPushButton(self.CheckIn)
    self.chkin_reg_submit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 370, 91, 23))
    self.chkin_reg_submit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("chkin_reg_submit"))
    self.chkin_reg_device_in = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.CheckIn)
    self.chkin_reg_device_in.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 280, 211, 20))
    self.chkin_reg_device_in.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("chkin_reg_device_in"))
    self.chkin_drpmn_name = QtGui.QComboBox(self.CheckIn)
    self.chkin_drpmn_name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 250, 221, 22))
    self.chkin_drpmn_name.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("chkin_drpmn_name"))
    self.chkin_drpmn_name.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.chkin_drpmn_name.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))


def retranslateUi(self, CheckIn):
    self.chkin_reg_submit.setText(_translate("CheckIn", "Check In", None))
    self.chkin_reg_descr.setText(_translate("CheckIn", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">Description:</span></p></body></html>", None))
    self.chkin_reg_name.setText(_translate("CheckIn", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">Name:</span></p></body></html>", None))
    self.chkin_reg_device.setText(_translate("CheckIn", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">Device:</span></p></body></html>", None))
    self.chkin_reg_serial.setText(_translate("CheckIn", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">Serial #:</span></p></body></html>", None))
    self.chkin_reg_asset.setText(_translate("CheckIn", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">Asset Tag #:</span></p></body></html>", None))
    self.chkin_new_submit.setText(_translate("CheckIn", "Check In", None))
    self.chkin_drpmn_name.setItemText(0, _translate("CheckIn", "User 1", None))
    self.chkin_drpmn_name.setItemText(1, _translate("CheckIn", "User 2", None))
```

Comment: you need to provide code that you have tried and what errors do you get, your question is unclear (at least for me). If your question is not about writing to an excel spreadsheet (as you say you have *covered* it), there is no need to talk about that in the question.

Comment: Use the `ui` variable?

Comment: Sorry I added more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so simple! All you need is connecting the `currentTextChanged(QString)` signal of the `QComboBox` to the `setText(QString)` slot of your `QLineEdit`.

```
connect(comboBox, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString text)),
        lineEdit, SLOT(setText(QString text)));
```

This connection makes your `QLineEdit` to display the current item selected by `QComboBox`.

If you would need to add something else to that text, you need to implement your own slot which should be connected to `currentIndexChanged` or `currentTextChanged` signals of the `QComboBox`.

Comment: Hello Frogatto thank you for your input! I've updated my initial question with more information. is it possible you could give me an example with what I posted above? For example when some one selects User 1 I want user 1's device, serial, asset tag and description added to the QLineEdits. So each user will have it's own defined set of device serial asset tag and description.

Comment: Frogatto I got the text working where the text of the item picked in the combo box appears in the lineedit... i'm still not understanding how I can attach other text to that combo selection and then have it displayed in specific lineedit